# Replacing coroutine intrinsics in experimental/resumable

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, coroutine, c++-winrt

I'm trying to compile a class which makes use of cppwinrt using llvm-clang 8.0. The only blocker at the moment is that clang can't find the implementations for coroutine intrinsics defined in `experimental/resumable`. These are the intrinsics defined in VC++ header `experimental/resumable`:

```
extern "C" size_t _coro_resume(void *);
extern "C" void _coro_destroy(void *);
extern "C" size_t _coro_done(void *);
#pragma intrinsic(_coro_resume)
#pragma intrinsic(_coro_destroy)
#pragma intrinsic(_coro_done)
```

According to clang documentation these are the coroutine intrinsics in clang:

```
void  __builtin_coro_resume(void *addr);
void  __builtin_coro_destroy(void *addr);
bool  __builtin_coro_done(void *addr);
```

If I manually replace the intrinsics in the header with the clang ones it compiles. However this is obviously not a portable solution. Is there anyway I can achieve the same result using some pragma hack or compile time header replacement?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give a solution, but it is not verified because I haven't clang on my machine.

```
#ifdef __clang__
    size_t _coro_resume(void *addr) { __builtin_coro_resume(addr); return 0; }
    void _coro_destroy(void *addr) { __builtin_coro_destroy(addr); }
    size_t _coro_done(void *addr) { return __builtin_coro_done(addr) ? 1 : 0; }
#else
    extern "C" size_t _coro_resume(void *);
    extern "C" void _coro_destroy(void *);
    extern "C" size_t _coro_done(void *);
    #pragma intrinsic(_coro_resume)
    #pragma intrinsic(_coro_destroy)
    #pragma intrinsic(_coro_done)
#endif
```

It seems that the return value of the functions are ignored.

Comment: I already specified I can get it to work by manually editing the header. What I need is a portable solution.